# What can I do so MD files would be more visible in Notepad++?

Tags: styles, notepad++

I have a problem. Content of files in md file format is barely visible in Notepad++. 
I use "Solarized" style/theme. I cannot see a way to change the look just for md files alone.
Files written in python, txt, C++ are handled OK. Just MD files are causing issues.
Image attached: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpSM3.png)

Is there a way to do something about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Notepad++ has a built-in "Language" for Markdown. You've probably installed a plugin, or somehow imported a user-defined language. To make adjustments, go to the menu Language > Define Your Language... and examine the dialog.

Make sure you choose "Markdown" from the drop-down box at the top of that dialog window.

Under the tab "Folder & Default", click the "Styler" button for "Default Style". Select a nice neutral grey or whatever suits your fancy with that theme. If there are other colors which are difficult to read, they can be adjusted similarly in the other tabs.

[image: Screenshot of the relevant controls on the dialog]

Comment: Thank you, sounds like the way to go. I cannot see "Folder & Default" tab in 'User-Defined" menu. Where is it?